# Copy tables structure and data to different user

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of tables with data in one user schema.
I want a copy of those to another user.

Can this be done with SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Are the 2 schema on the same database?

Comment: Yes they are in the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two users are on the same database, and provided sufficient `GRANTS` are present, then just run the below statement in the new user schema:

```
create table <tablename> as select * from olduser.<tablename>;
```

---

### EDIT:

Copy the below set of statements in a text file. Replace `<oldueser>` with the existing schema name and `<path>` with a path in the unix/windows machine where you want the spool to be written. Run this file in the existing schema. A spool file will be written in the path specified with the name `tbls.sql`. Take this `tbls.sql` and run it in the new schema, where you want the tables to be replicated.

```
set head off
set line 100000
set line 100000
set feedback off
spool <path>/tbls.sql
select 'CREATE TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME ||' AS SELECT * FROM <OLDUSER>.'||TABLE_NAME||';'
FROM user_tables; 
spool off
set feedback on
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for ALL tables within the schema without typing them individually?

Comment: @bukko Updated the answer. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using export command in command prompt i.e.

```
c:\>exp userid=userid(sql admin)/password owner=username(from which user) direct=y file=filename.dmp
```

to import this by using

```
c:\>imp userid=userid(sql admin)/password file=filename.dmp fromuser=username(from which user) touser=username(imported username)
```

by using this you have to export data into a dump file and after taht import it into another user

Answer (score 0):

`create schema2.tablename as select * from schema1.tablename`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can export the first schema and import in the second schema - I would go for this if there are not any reasons preventing you to do that.
   [Documentation is here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm)
2. Provided you have access grants, you can write a small script to do that for you. 
   You can select all your source user's tables using the query:

   `SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner = <source_schema>`

Loop through all of them and create the new tables by using execute immediate. ([Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm))

```
execute immediate 'create <dest>.<tablename> as select * from <source>.<tablename>';
```

`dest` and `source` are the name of the schema.
`tablename` is the name of the table as taken from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be "CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT" will be useful for you?

See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm)

Here is [a good article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm)